# Unicode input with raw_input() in python

Tags: python, unicode

I´am just starting to learn python using LPTHW, and it´s really good. 
I´am just a couple of days in to my studies and come up to excercise 16 it looks like this:

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file.  Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%r\n%r\n%r\n" % (line1, line2, line3))

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

The problem is that i'm from a country with the letters "Å", "Ä" and  "Ö" in the alphabet, but when  i am using these letters the output in the file (test.txt) looks something like this:
    u'hej'
    u'\xc5je'
    u'l\xe4get'

When i decode a string a can do something like this:
    "hallå".decode("utf-8")

And it will print just fine

But i also want the input from a user to be correct, even when using odd characters.
I have tried different things that either does not work or gives me errors when running, like for example

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ").decode("utf-8")
```

I tried to google my problems but i did´t feel like the answers given was not very straight forward or written for much more experienced users.

If someone would take some time to explain the encoding/decoding of unicode characters in a beginner firendly way and give me an example of how i can get it to work i would really appriciate it

If it helps, iam on Windows 10, running python 2.7.10 and my system locale is set to swedish

Comment: Are you running from a Windows command console, or from IDLE? It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to decode stdin.  It generally works from the Console but IDEs sometimes replace the stdin object and don't always support the encoding parameter.  I also modernized the code a bit, using `with` and `io.open` to handle encodings.  Note that the file will be written in UTF-8, so open it with Notepad to see it correctly.  Using `type <filename>` from the console will try to display the file with the console's stdout encoding.

```
#!python2
import sys
import io

script, filename = sys.argv

print "We're going to erase %s." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

with io.open(filename, 'wt', encoding='utf8') as target:
    target.write(u"%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your output indicates that `raw_input()` already accepts `Å`, `ä` just fine in your environment.

Either your code does not correspond to the output or your IDE is too helpful. `raw_input()` should return `str` type (bytes) but the output shows that you're saving text representations of `unicode` objects: `u'hej' u'\xc5je' u'l\xe4get'`.

The smallest code change that would produce your desirable result is using `%s` (save string as is) instead of `%r` (save its ascii printable representation as returned by `repr()` function) in the format string as suggested in [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32726746/4279).

---

> If someone would take some time to explain the encoding/decoding of unicode characters in a beginner firendly way and give me an example of how i can get it to work i would really appriciate it

Unicode handling on Python 2 requires understanding of what API returns text and what API returns binary data. Some API use a mixture such as ascii-based network protocols.

Python 2 allows `str` type to represent both human-readable text and binary data and it may create confusion. I recommend to start with Python 3 that is more strict for Unicode-related issues.

---

In general, while working with Unicode you should convert encoded text into Unicode on input as soon as possible (e.g., using `.decode()`) and convert Unicode text to bytes on output as late as possible. [@Mark Tolonen's answer demonstrate this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32746643/4279):

- it uses `.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)` to decode bytes returned from `raw_input()` into Unicode text. If `raw_input()` already returns Unicode in your environment (to check `print type(raw_input('input something'))`) then you could omit `.decode()` call
- `io.open(..., encoding='utf-8').write(u'some text')` convert Unicode text to bytes (encodes it using utf-8 encoding).

This general approach is known as [Unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

`.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)` may fail. To support arbitrary Unicode input in Windows console, [install `win-unicode-console` Python package](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a representation of the string, rather than the actual encoded Unicode string, to your file. Use

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this format:

`f = open('file.txt', 'w')
s = u'\u221A'
f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))`

here: 
`line1 = raw_input("> ").encode('utf-8')`
so goes for line2 and line3